# Rotate Image but not Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I am using background image in the canvas. I would like to rotate only background image by 90 degree but context should not be rotated. If I use css transform then whole canvas get rotated. How can I do ?

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
        
ctx.rect(20, 30, 200, 40);
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.lineWidth="2";
ctx.stroke();  
        
$(function(){
    //$('#canvas').css({'transform':'rotate(90deg)'});
});
```

```css
#canvas{
  background: #789;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body{
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1600x800); background-size: 100%; background-position: -80px -50px;">Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
```

Comment: Have you tried to rotate image using  rotate JQuery http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/?

Comment: I've just tried as suggested but no luck.

Comment: This would be a somewhat dirty hack, but you can try to move the canvas into a <div>, rotate that div, give it the background image, and rotate the canvas in the opposite direction.

Comment: actually this would make whole app very complicated, there are many dynamic elements, I am avoiding touching anything in the canvas part unfortunately.

Comment: @KiiroSora09 made a working solution, but if you have many dynamic elements, you should probably consider using a canvas library that would handle stuff like rotated background images for you.

Comment: First create 360 versions of your image... haha only joking. You are much better off calling this image in your canvas code, and rotating it there, then draw your rectangle on top of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/asg8kakn/3/).

I created a `container` div that has the same size as the canvas element, then I added a pseudo element on the `container` div that will serve as the rotated background. I don't think we can use pseudo elements on the canvas itself since the canvas only shows it's contents when it's not supported.

Answer (score 4):

By using a pseudo :before element, you can rotate only the background image.

```
#canvas:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1600x800) 0 0 repeat;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

(via http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/)